# Tree with checkboxes | DJANGO

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-mptt, django-widget

I have model `Program` with ManyToManyField `function`. I need too create form where as in the picture below where users can select and add functions to program. In other words I need TreeView with checkbox. How create such widget?

[image]

I found **django-mptt** app which as I understand allows me to create tree. Is this app good for my task? Can someone who worked with this app show me example cause I am comfused with concept of this app. Finally is this app can give flexible configuration inside template? I mean I need to add checkboxes.

**models.py:**

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=250)

class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=250)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Function(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=250)
     task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Program(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=250)
    function = models.ManyToManyField("Function")
```

Comment: Do you find out any answer for this question? @nurzhan-nogerbek